# pubsubhubbub - What is the difference between sync and async when sucribing to a feed?

Tags: asynchronous, subscribe, websub, subscriber

I am trying to implement `pubsubhubbub` as a subscriber to https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/

When it comes time to subscribe via the [debuger](https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe) the field `verify type` offers 2 possibilities:

- asynchronous
- synchronous

Unfortunately the section `5.2 subscription validation` from [PubSubHubbub Core 0.4 -- Working Draft](http://pubsubhubbub.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pubsubhubbub-core-0.4.html#discovery) doesn't give details about the verify type.

Does sync/async make any difference for the callback script when sucribing to a feed via pubsubhubbub ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PubSubHubbub 0.4 brings many updates and enhancements.

Among them:

- Breaking change: **“sync”** mode of subscription verification has been removed.

Anf for information:

*hub.verify_token, permanent subscriptions and Hub-initiated subscription renewals have been also removed.*

from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pubsubhubbub/7RPlYMds4RI/2mIHQTdV3aoJ

**Answer:** It makes no more difference now, just use `async` as verify type.